# Unable to parse CloudStorageAccount

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My code:

```
CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=your_storage_account_name;AccountKey=your_storage_account_key");
```

always returns false. I'm only able to get it working for the connecting string "UseDevelopmentStorage=true". For testing purposes I need to run it with another (dummy) connection string but I'm not able to get it to parse. Please advice.

the exception thrown is "No valid combination of account information found"

Comment: Are you trying in Development or in Production?
Have you tried DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https?
Are you sure your data account is right?

Comment: Why don't you store the connection string in a ServiceConfiguration file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (use HTTPS)

```
    Dim account As CloudStorageAccount

    If CloudStorageAccount.TryParse("AccountName=youraccount;AccountKey=YourAccountKey;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https", account) Then
        Dim tableClient As CloudTableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient()
        Dim table As CloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("Test")
        table.CreateIfNotExists()
    End If
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use an account key with a valid size and format.
Try to use this: kiRN0h4jm24fyLZIT7y5+iA8nLE+5QUPisiFNJ/9bH4ws6T/m9sHmr22/dw0i+31Dgb/9JxYjj/V8SHxVPp7IA==